Nuxt 3 dynamic index page routing
How to make the page index routing dynamic? Which folder structure allows to reproduce this behavior?
For example '/', '/about', '/register', etc only for pages/index.vue project directory.
I want create navigation by section scrolling, with no hash mode spa.

Can you rephrase your question? What do you mean? You can do pages/[...slug].vue - https://nuxt.com/docs/migration/pages-and-layouts

Simply write a global middleware
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to) => {
  const first = useState('first', () => true)
  if (!first.value) return
  first.value = false

  const index = ...
  if (to.path !== index) return index
})

demo
